# list with lots of data in laravel

Tags: laravel, list, pagination

I have a bank with more than 10000 registered users.
It turns out that my method is listing everything and it causes a very slow return of data.

```
$users = \App\User::all();
```

it is taking almost 40 seconds to show the list with the paginations.

How can I solve this? Filters?

Comment: You can use WHERE clause like in SQL by calling `\App\User::where`

Comment: 40s for 10k records is a lot. Are you sure you're not just using too many relationships in the view? In any case, you should paginate in the controller for these cases. Also, you can use `::cursor()` instead of `::all()` to get a memory-light iterator.

Comment: He has no relationships.
If I'm going to use :: cursor (), would I have an example?

Comment: `$users = App\User::cursor();` `foreach ($users as $user) { ... }`. the cursor method returns an object you iterate over instead of loading 10000 instances of a Model in memory.

Answer (score 0):

2 thing should be indicate:

First the relations of this model may be complex and maybe in rest of code you use `lazy load` instead of `eager load`.
But az you said in comments this model is not complex.

Second:maybe you test this query in phpmyadmin and it take time better and fast and it make you surprised.

Phpmyadmin use `limit` automatilcaly.you can `chunck` or `paginate` your records for this purpose and make your performance much better.

Comment: I just read about it, but I didn't get it right. In my current situation, although it takes almost 40s, my View shows all users with pagination ... everything working. I would have to do this pagination manually?

Comment: No eloquent has it.see its documentationit is different from paginate in view .

Comment: what I need is to continue to page but like this. my list has 5000 records, but it takes too long. so i wanted when i moved on to the next one to do a new search every 10 out of 10 and not all 5000 records.

Answer (score 0):

Why you don't try laravel paginate()

```
$users = \App\User::paginate(25);
```

Comment: That way it was super fast, but it only shows 25 data.